What should I do if ifstream does not work in the switch case?
In the code snippet below, I'm calling 2 different files. The first time everything works and the text is extracted from the file correctly, but when the second file is called from within the switch case, the compiler writes an error:
error: jump to case label
61 | case 2:
   | ^

Does anyone know how to leave the switch case and ifstream construction and make everything work?
float bank(int third_q, int forth_q) {
    int k;
    ifstream file1("vklad1.txt");
    char ch1;
    while (file1.get(ch1)) {
        cout << ch1;
    }
    file1.close();
    cin >> third_q;
    while (third_q != 1 || third_q != 2) {
        switch(third_q)
            {
                case 1:
                    double sum, percent, duration, end_sum;
                    cout << "Введите сумму своих сбережений:";
                    cin >> sum;
                    cout << endl;
                    cout << "Введите процент вклада:";
                    cin >> percent;
                    cout << endl;
                    cout << "Введите количество лет (если процент годовой) или месяцев (если процент месячный) на которые вы планируете положить деньги на вклад:";
                    cin >> duration;
                    cout << endl;
                    cout << "Итоговая сумма будет равна ";
                    end_sum = sum * pow((1 + percent/100), duration);
                    cout << end_sum << '\n';
                    k = 1;
                    break;
                case 2: 
                    k = 1;
                    break;
                default: 
                    cout << "Неверный ввод, повторите попытку." << '\n';
                    cin >> third_q;
                    break;
                }
        if (k == 1) {
            break;
        }
    }
    cout << "Хотите ли вы узнать о рисках, связанных с этим вариантом вложения?\n1)Да\n2)Нет" << endl;
    cin >> forth_q;
    while (forth_q != 1 || forth_q != 2) {
        switch (forth_q)
        {
            case 1:
            ifstream file2("vklad2.txt");
                char ch2;
                while (file2.get(ch2)) {
                    cout << ch2;
                }
                file2.close();
                k = 2;
                break;
            case 2: 
                k = 2;
                break;
            default:
                cout << "Неверный ввод, повторите попытку." << '\n';
                cin >> forth_q;
                break;
        }
        if (k == 2) {
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}


please include the complete compiler error message in the question. Also posting a [mcve] would help enormously to help you. See here for the error messages others get from the code you posted https://godbolt.org/z/T1sbYYfKG and how many errors there are and how difficult it is to see the actual error you are trying to ask about

in switch (forth_q) you are constructing a ifstream in case 1:. This is not allowed directly.
Put the case in braces to introduce a new scope: case 1: {...} break;

Think about while (forth_q != 1 || forth_q != 2). When will this condition be false?

it looks like function arguments should be passed by reference. Also this code shouldn't compile because  swicth cannot contain variable declarations, but can contain compound statements

Questions seeking debugging help should generally provide a [mre] of the problem, which includes a function main and all #include directives, as well as the exact input required to reproduce the problem. This allows other people to easily test your program, by simply using copy&paste.

Read the entire error message, not just the first part of it:
<source>: In function 'float bank(int, int)':
<source>:60:18: error: jump to case label
   60 |             case 2:
      |                  ^
<source>:52:22: note:   crosses initialization of 'std::ifstream file2'
   52 |             ifstream file2("vklad2.txt");
      |                

A switch statement's case labels do not create independent scopes.  They are just where execution of the entire switch block begins when given the corresponding values.  I fact, if you don't break at the end of each case then execution will fall through to the next one.
That means that file2 exists in the scope of case 2 and default, but because execution began at the case 2 label, the initialization of file2 would be skipped and so it would be uninitialized if accessed from case 2 or default.
The way to deal with that is to introduce your own independant scopes for each case using {}:
switch (forth_q)
{
    case 1:
    {
        ifstream file2("vklad2.txt");
        char ch2;
        while (file2.get(ch2)) {
            cout << ch2;
        }
        file2.close();
        k = 2;
        break;
    }
    case 2:
    {
        k = 2;
        break;
    }
    default:
    {
        cout << "Неверный ввод, повторите попытку." << '\n';
        cin >> forth_q;
        break;
    }
}

Now file2 only exists within the scope between the case 1 and case 2 labels.
Note that the same issue exists in your other switch statement with sum, percent, duration, and end_sum, but the compiler allows it since they are trivial objects and are therefore allowed to exist in an uninitialized state.

While-loop checks condition before entering loop body, so after
cin >> third_q;
while (third_q != 1 || third_q != 2) {

we cannot expect statements in case 1 or case 2 being executed. The condition check should come after the switch. Thankfully we have  a do\while loop.
Next problem: this is not legal C++
            case 1:
                   ifstream file2("vklad2.txt");

And some compilers don't like or even have implementation flaws related to
            case 1:
                double sum, percent, duration, end_sum;

switch is the most treacherous structure in C++, because of variety of permitted edge case. Syntax also alters between C and C++. Cases should be statements or list of statements, possibly with break; to exit the switch structure. Transfer of control via switch-case or goto is not permitted to enter the scope of a variable. This allows compound statements, i.e. you should wrap code in {} to make it a single statement, which is the scope of variable. If visibility of variable is required inother cases, it should be "lifted" to the outer code-block. On pure technicality control structures like for(), while(), etc. may straddle several switch-cases.
Your function doesn't take its parameters by reference and this looks like a semantic error, becuase you wouldn't know what the values entered were outside of function.

Transfer of control is allowed to enter the scope of trivial objects as long as their declaration doesn't contain an initializer.  See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/goto (the same rules apply to goto and switch).

@MilesBudnek goto and switch got different rules, for goto that's the case (Ba Dum Tish). In switch that works curiously differently or something like Duff device could have problems (although some compilers have known bugs). You can place variable declaraion before any of switches according to rules you recite but not inside of case... the  switch happens right after the... switch but before first label. Note, in now C you can just write  ;  after  case-label before declaration and initialization of variable instead of { }

@MilesBudnek https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/switch "Because transfer of control is not permitted to enter the scope of a variable, if a declaration statement is encountered inside the statement, it has to be scoped in its own compound statement"

That switch page refers to the rules on the goto page.  I can find no differentiation in the actual standard between the two cases.  For instance in [stmt.dcl]: "unless all such variables have vacuous initialization ([basic.life]), the transfer of control shall not be a jump.75". Where footnote 75 explicitly says: "75) The transfer from the condition of a switch statement to a case label is considered a jump in this respect.". That seems pretty clear that switch is allowed to jump over vacuous initializations.

Also, while it's not definitive proof that it's technically correct, all three major compilers allow jumping over a vacuous initialization and reject jumping over a non-vacuous one.
